# How do you turn off AGC in an Icom IC-705?

Tags: icom-ic-705

I can only see options to set it to fast, medium and slow, but not to turn it off. I checked the manual and I can't find it. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [basic manual](https://icomuk.co.uk/files/icom/PDF/productManual/IC-705_ENG_Basic_1.pdf) describes the procedure on page 4-3. It reads a bit counterintuitive since apparently the time constant of any of the three presets (fast, mid, slow) can be set to "off" rather than "off" being a preset in itself.